# How sails controller can route to angularjs page?

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I have an sails app, can I use res.redirect() inside a controller to an angularjs home page?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use following options in your angularjs controller.
1) $location.path("path");
2) $location.url("path");
3) $window.location("path");
```

for more details you can refer  [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)
If you are using **ui-route** then you can use **$state.go("path");**

Comment: Oh, I mean from sails.js controller to angularjs, not from angularjs to sails.js. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can `use` something like this.

```
module.exports ={
   index: function (req, res) {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }  
}
```

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/res-redirect

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.